# How to add checkboxlist selected value as column in gridview dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, gridview

I have a table which contains due date column and I bind checkboxlist with this in table by using following code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[duedate]
(
    [duedateid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [duedate] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ON
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (1, N'Apr')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (2, N'May')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (3, N'Jun')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (4, N'Jul')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (5, N'Aug')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (6, N'Sep')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (7, N'Oct')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (8, N'Nov')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (9, N'Dec')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (10, N'Jan')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (11, N'Feb')
INSERT [dbo].[duedate] ([duedateid], [duedate]) VALUES (12, N'Mar')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[duedate] OFF
```

My c# code to bind checkboxlist data from database

```
public void bindchbxlstduedate()
{
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
     {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Readduedat";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = sdr["duedate"].ToString();
                item.Value = sdr["duedateid"].ToString();
                chbxlstduedate.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]

We have another table fee master which contains students fee details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[feemaster]
(
     [feeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [feetype] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [feename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [classname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [duemonth] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [feeamount] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
     [feeactive] [bit] NULL,
     [feecatename] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (1, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname],   [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (13, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS  Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (2, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (3, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (4, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (5, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (6, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (7, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (8, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) 
VALUES (9, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')

INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (10, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (11, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (12, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (14, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (15, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (16, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (17, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')

  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename],  [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (18,  N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)),  1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (19, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (20, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (21, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (22, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (23, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (24, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
        INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (25, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (26, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (27, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (28, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (29, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (30, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (31, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (32, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (33, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (34, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (35, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (36, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (37, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (38, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (39, N'Annual', N'Maintenance Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (40, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (41, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (42, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (43, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (44, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (45, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (46, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (47, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (48, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (49, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (50, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (51, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
 INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (52, N'One Time', N'Prospectus & Registration Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (53, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (54, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (55, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (56, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (57, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (58, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (59, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (60, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (61, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (62, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (63, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (64, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (65, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (66, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (67, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (68, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (69, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (70, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (71, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
     INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (72, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (73, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (74, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (75, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (76, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (77, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (78, N'One Time', N'Admission Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (79, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (80, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (81, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (82, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (83, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (84, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (85, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (86, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (87, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (88, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (89, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (90, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (91, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'NEW')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (92, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'PRENURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (93, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'NURSURY', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (94, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 0, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (95, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'I', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (96, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'II', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
   INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (97, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'III', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (98, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'IV', N'Apr', CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
    INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (99, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'V', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
       INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename],  [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (100,  N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VI', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1,  N'OLD')


  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (101, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VII', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (102, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'VIII', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (103, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'IX', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (104, N'Annual', N'Computer Fee', N'X', N'Apr', CAST(650.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
  INSERT [dbo].[feemaster] ([feeId], [feetype], [feename], [classname], [duemonth], [feeamount], [feeactive], [feecatename]) VALUES (105, N'Annual', N'Examination Fee', N'KG', N'Apr', CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(15, 2)), 1, N'OLD')
```

this is the data for april month only and we have similar data for all months now I want when we select april or march or any other month of year or two months of year from checkbox list then from feemaster table we want to show data month wise for particular student of particular class and section into gridview.

[image]

Please any one suggest us how we can do that.

Comment: 2 options - get all data from server and after selecting checkboxes filter this collection, or after selecting checkboxes - send new query to sql server so it will return filtered data. I suggest option one :)

Comment: thanks friends but how we add month name as column name in gridview dynamically.suppose a student want to pay two moths apr and may fee at a time then what we do.

Comment: When You're getting data from server, group it by months in code behind using Linq. Then You will be able to hide/show every group as checkbox checked status will be changed.

Comment: please provide some code or hint